# UnrecognizedPropertyException Jersey 2.0 rc1 JSON to convert to Java Object

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

My Jersey Rest shows underlying error when the GET method id called. It shows unrecognizedproperty error, but the LastName property is there in DTO class. I am not sure why the error is coming up.

Error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "LastName" (Class com.shams.glassfishrs.dto.EmployeeDTO), not marked as ignorable| at [Source: java.io.StringReader@44863495; line: 1, column: 38] (through reference chain: com.shams.glassfishrs.dto.EmployeeDTO["LastName"])
```

The EmployeeDTO class.

```
package com.shams.glassfishrs.dto;

//@XmlRootElement
public class EmployeeDTO {
    String firstName;
    String LastName;
    int Age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public void setAge(int Age) {
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "{" + "\"firstName\":\"" + this.getFirstName() + "\"," + "\"LastName\":\"" + this.getLastName() + "\"," + "\"Age\":\"" + this.getAge() + "\"}";
    }

}
```

Dependancy in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.0-rc1'   
}
```

Rest Call method in Controller class

```
package com.shams.glassfishrs;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.shams.glassfishrs.dto.EmployeeDTO;


@Path("")
public class Controller {
    ///@GET
    //// @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Path("employee/")
    public String printMsg() throws Exception{
        String employee = "{\"firstName\":\"firstName\",\"lastName\":\"firstName\",\"Age\":\"34\"}";
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
        ObjectMapper map=new ObjectMapper();
        //map.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        EmployeeDTO emp=map.readValue(employee, EmployeeDTO.class);
        System.out.println("First Name:" + emp.getFirstName() + ",lastName:" + emp.getLastName() + ",age:" + emp.getAge());
        //return Response.ok(employee.toString()).build();
        return employee.toString();
    }
}
```

Here the intention is to test the JSON to Java Object and vice versa from AngularJS view part. The Rest end itself is failing and showing above error. I am not looking for the ignoreProperty annotation here. Can any one please help me to understand the reason of this error and solution to convert to Java Object including LastName?

Comment: Is there a reason "LastName" is capitalized? If you _must_ have it capitalized in the JSON, you should add `@JsonProperty("LastName")` (on the field or property) in the DTO class. Jackson expected lowecase

Comment: Thanks, it worked.... +1